# SQL Server databases tables exist, but are not visible

Tags: sql-server

I have an odd issue on a Microsoft SQL Server that I manage. Two of the largest tables in a database are not visible in the Object Explorer.

When doing Right Click > Tasks > Shrink > Files, on the database, it is showing the data file as 99% unused. However in the following screenshot it is clear that there's over 500GB used:

[image: sys.database_files shows over 500GB used]

The disk usage by table shows these two tables have over 1B records and is the majority of space reserved in the data file.

[image: Disk Usage by Table]

However, when looking in the object explorer, the tables does not exist:

[image: See example here for the AccountHistory Table]

I know the table exists because I am able to run select queries against it. The SQL Server version is Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) Standard Edition (64-bit). I am also using a sysadmin account, and have confirmed that it is not a view.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Cheers,

Comment: Probably some joker has used [sp_addextendedproperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addextendedproperty-transact-sql) to add the `microsoft_database_tools_support` extended property to those tables, hiding them from view in the SSMS Object Explorer. Does executing `select * from sys.fn_listextendedproperty(default, N'SCHEMA', N'dbo', N'TABLE', N'AccountHistory', default, default);` return a row?

Comment: Do you have permissions to view the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you have temporal tables in your environment. The history table will show up underneath the base table in SSMS. Here's a screenshot from the WideWorldImporters sample database from MS:

[image]

Comment: Cheers this was it - legend!